# JS:How to send multiple files using FormData(jQuery Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data

In my form multiple file uploads are there,using `FormData` only one file is uploading ,though I'm selecting more than one file to upload,following is the code

**HTML**

```
<form name="uploadImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photo[]" value="">
<input type="file" name="photo[]" value="">
<input type="file" name="photo[]" value="">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
     var ajaxData = new FormData();
     ajaxData.append( 'action','uploadImages');
     jQuery.each($("input[name^='photo']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
        ajaxData.append('photo['+i+']', file);
      });
     $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        data: ajaxData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
       });
```

I'm using `PHP` at server,using `HTML attribute name` i,e `photo` only I'm able to save files,dynamic file names won't be work for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have an error in javascript: you're iterating only over files in one input please have a look at this

```
var ajaxData = new FormData();
ajaxData.append( 'action','uploadImages');
$.each($("input[type=file]"), function(i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files,function(j, file){
            ajaxData.append('photo['+j+']', file);
        })
});
```

example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnrC7/1/)

Comment: its working fine,but the issue is when I upload same files(which have same names) then getting error,is there any chance to handle this.

Comment: Yuriy thanks for your help, the error which described above is `server side` error,nothing do with `JS`.Though I'm describing the error: when choose same file twice at time then I getting error 500 i,e. `Internal server error`.

Comment: Yuriy,can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455688/how-to-initialize-jquery-tabs-after-complete-execution-of-a-user-defined-functio),if get any idea,let me know please.Thanks

Comment: I think PHP likes `[]`, I think MVC likes `[0]`

Answer (score 2):

in front end

```
<form name="uploadImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo[]" value=""/>
    <input type="file" name="photo[]" value=""/>
    <input type="file" name="photo[]" value=""/>
    <button id="btn">btn</button>
</form>
        <script>
            $(function(){
     var ajaxData = new FormData();
     ajaxData.append( 'action','uploadImages');
     $.each($("input[type=file]"), function(i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files,function(j, file){
            ajaxData.append('photo['+j+']', file);
          $('#btn').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
        url:'https://stores-govan.c9users.io/test',
          type:"POST",
          data:ajaxData,
          processData:false,
          contentType:false,
          success:function(){
            },
          crossDomain:true
        })
        })

        })
     });

})
</script>
```

at the backend (nodejs) add this(using multer)

```
var multer=require('multer')
app.post('/test',upload.array('photo[]',6),function(req ,res,next){
            var images=[]
               if(req.files){
               for(var i=0;i<req.files.length;i++){
               images[i]=req.files[i].filename }
               }
               console.log(images)
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="file" name="Attachment[]" class="form-control TheFiles" />
```

The previous answer has a little error that was fixed on the next code, and gonna works to send multiple files via ajax:

```
var formData = new FormData();
        $.each($(".TheFiles"), function (i, obj) {                
            $.each(obj.files, function (j, file) {                    
                formData.append('Attachment[' + i + ']', file); // is the var i against the var j, because the i is incremental the j is ever 0
            });
        });
        formData.append('Destination', Destination); //add more variables that you need
        formData.append('ReplyTo', ReplyTo);//add more variables that you need
        formData.append('Body', Body);//add more variables that you need
```

optionally just for you can see my ajax config

```
$.ajax({
             url: 'YourUrl',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
             success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $(Here).text('Enviado com sucesso');
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Não deixe nenhum campo vazio");
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```js
var data = new FormData();
for( var i = 0, len = document.getElementById('attachment').files.length; i < len; i++ ){
    data.append( "files" + i, document.getElementById('attachment').files[i] );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Those answers do not work.

```
var ajaxData = new FormData();
ajaxData.append( 'action','uploadImages');
$.each($("input[type=file]"), function(i, obj) {
    $.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
        ajaxData.append('photo['+j+']', file);//i had to change "i" by "j"
    })
});
```