# Unable to upload multiple files in .ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, handler, ashx

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'

This is the error that shows up in my response header.
I can't send multiple files through ajax to the handler.

**jQuery**

```
            var data = new FormData();
            jQuery.each($('#multipleFileUpload')[0].files, function (i, file) {
                data.append('file-' + i, file);
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "../handlers/project/sell/galleryUpload.ashx",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                data: data,
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Erro no envio de fotos do projecto. " + data.status);
                }
            });
```

**Handler:**

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in context.Request.Files)
{ ... } 
//it gives error in this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem.  I don't know why, but the problem arises when iterating over the context.Request.Files collection with a `foreach` loop.

Instead, use a traditional `for` loop and explicitly cast to an HttpPostedFile instead.

```
HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count;i++ )
{
    HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
    string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(fname);
}
```

Source:
http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f2a2f1ee-e18a-416b-893e-883c800f83f4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

AjaxUpload is browser dependent, what browser are you using?

Is your form with enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Take a look in this answer :

[JS:How to send multiple files using FormData(jQuery Ajax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496407/jshow-to-send-multiple-files-using-formdatajquery-ajax)

Comment: i use google chrome and all others, but i use the same way to upload and doesn't return error to one file, but multiple has errors!

Comment: To upload one file you use exactly the same code above?