# Unable to send array of uploaded files to controller in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, multipartform-data

I have a contact form that let user allow to upload multiple files. I'm sending all the files to my controller using ajax approach with `formData`. I want to get all the uploaded files into my controller from where I can process the files.

When I do dd(); it returns **null**.

Blade

```
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data")}}">

       <div id="dropzoneLover"   class="dropzone"></div>

      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="documents[]" multiple/>

</form>
```

Javascript

```
    <script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    $("#dropzoneLover").dropzone({
        url: "{{route('form_for_car_lovers')}}",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,

        init: function() {
            dzClosure = this; 

            document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", 
        function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                dzClosure.processQueue();
            }),

                this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
                    formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
                    $('input[name="documents[]"]').each(function (index, member) 
                    {
                        var getDocs = $(member).val();
                        formData.append('documents[]', getDocs);
                  });

                }),

        }
    });

    
    </script>
```

Controller

```
public function myfiles()
{
        $test =  $request['documents'];
        $test1 =  $request->documents;
        $test2 =  $request->file('documents');

        dd($test,$test1,$test2); // All variables returns null
}
```

Comment: How are you sending these files - Where is your `$.ajax` request to send all `formData` ? Also your Javascript logic is incorrect - thats not how files can be grabbed and appended to formData

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS:How to send multiple files using FormData(jQuery Ajax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496407/jshow-to-send-multiple-files-using-formdatajquery-ajax)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping 
I' m using dropzone to send all the form data to controller. I can see all of my values coming into controller except this one. 
I just upadted my code, please check

Comment: @Dmitry Nope........

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
Please see my updated Javascrip code

Comment: @Dmitry Please check my updated JavaScript code.

Comment: Please a minimal working example of this code to be able to debug it

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
For sake of your convenience, I just included a screenshot of my ajax call from Network Tab. Please check now

Comment: @Shaan Please go to headers and check whether any file is being sent to the contorller or NOT. go to headers and all the way bottom and see formData

Comment: @AlwaysHelping This is the very last line under Headers "file[0]: (binary)"..

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
Any luck :(

Comment: @AlwaysHelping
Sure, Thanks...
It's now more than 2 days and I' m stuck over this issue.:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221558/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-shaan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to append the actual `file` object in your `formData` like this below:

**jQuery** (this code is tested and works perfectly)

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$("#dropzoneLover").dropzone({
    url: "upload.php",
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple:true,
    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;
        //Click
        document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
        //On sending
        myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) { 
            formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
            var getDocuments = $('input[name="documents[]"]')[0].files
            $.each(getDocuments, function(index, file) {
                formData.append('documents[]', file);
            });
            //All the other formData goes below this

        });
    }
});
```

**In your laravel controller**

```
var_dump($request->file('documents'))
```

Comment: Prefect !
It's working.,,
I really appreciate your all the efforts and time. I was stuck over this issue since last 2 days and you helped me to sort it out. I' m very happy and I appreciate  your expertise. 

It's my honor to meet one of the  Laravel Pro developers here at this platform. 
God Bless you !

Comment: @Shaan happy to help brother. Just wondering if you had the same approach ?

Comment: I just pasted my solution below. Please check

Comment: @Shaan Nice. Same way of doing it but JS version of it. Glad all is working. I knew that we have to use this way. Since the two dropzone were conflicting with each other so i wanted to make sure i try everything with dropzone itselft first and then move onto jQuery each solution - Anyways. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative approach.

I replaced my code

```
   $('input[name="documents[]"]').each(function (index, member) 
     {
       var getDocs = $(member).val();
       formData.append('documents[]', getDocs);
    });
```

with this

```
 var getDocuments = document.getElementById('documents').files.length;
     for (var x = 0; x < getDocuments; x++) {
        formData.append("documents[]", 
        document.getElementById('documents').files[x]);
   }
```

Fetch and Split the array of values into Controller like this

```
$docs =  $request->documents;
    foreach ($docs as $doc) {
        $docname = $doc->getClientOriginalName();
        $docNames[] = $docname; // Store all Images into array
        $getuploadedImages = collect($docNames)->implode(',');

    }
  dd($getuploadedImages);
```